# MySQL getting value in same column as where conditional

Tags: mysql, sql

Need some help creating a query that can get me the results I want.

I'm pulling information from 2 tables in the mysql database.

```
TABLE 1 - tblclients
ID    firstname    lastname
1     Bob          K
2     Mary         J
3     Tod          M
```

tblcustomfieldsvalues.RelId = tblclients.ID

```
TABLE 2 - tblcustomfieldsvalues
ID    fieldid     RelId     value
1     15           3        3500
2     15           2        1500
3     17           3        Calp
4     17           2        Amazon
5     17           2        Calp

TABLE 3 - tblcustomfields (JUST FOR REFERENCE)
ID    FieldID     name
1     15          Purchase Amount        
2     17          Site
```

Desired Result:

I want to show the Purchase Amount in column 4 (FieldID = 15) where FieldID = 17 and value = 'calp'

```
ID    FirstName    LastName     Value
1     Tod           M           3500
2     Mary          J           1500
```

Current Query:

```
SELECT tblclients.id, tblclients.firstname, tblclients.lastname, tblcustomfieldsvalues.value FROM tblclients INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues ON tblclients.id = tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid WHERE tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid = 17 AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.value = 'Calp'
```

Current Result:

```
ID    FirstName    LastName     Value
1     Tod           M           Calp
2     Mary          J           Calp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this is conditional aggregation:

```
select c.*, value15 as value
from tblclients c join
     (select cfv.relid,
             max(case when fieldid = 15 then value end) as value15,
             sum(case when fieldid = 17 and value = 'Calp' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt17
      from tblcustomfieldsvalues cfv
      group by cfv.relid
     ) cv
where cnt17 > 0;
```

You can also do this with joins.  But you need separate joins for each for each of the fields:

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname, cfv15.value
FROM tblclients c INNER JOIN
     tblcustomfieldsvalues cfv17
     ON c.id = cfv17.relid AND
        cvf17.fieldid = 17 AND cfv17.value = 'Calp' INNER JOIN
     tblcustomfieldsvalues cfv15
     ON c.id = cfv15.relid AND
        cvf15.fieldid = 15;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I used the join version and it worked great. Just had to fix the typo from cvf.fieldid to cfv17.fieldid = 17 and cfv15.fieldid = 15.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what result you are expecting...
First of all I am sure you wrote fieldid=17 to get this result not 47.
If so
Your result is normal. You ask for fieldid 17 and also value 'Calp'.
Do you want fieldid 15 maybe ? Those were the ones has prices...
Or maybe

```
SELECT tblclients.id, tblclients.firstname, tblclients.lastname, tblcustomfieldsvalues.value FROM tblclients INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues ON tblclients.id = tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid WHERE tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid in (15,17) OR tblcustomfieldsvalues.value = 'Calp'
```

Your Query:

```
SELECT tblclients.id, tblclients.firstname, tblclients.lastname, tblcustomfieldsvalues.value FROM tblclients INNER JOIN tblcustomfieldsvalues ON tblclients.id = tblcustomfieldsvalues.relid WHERE tblcustomfieldsvalues.fieldid = 47 AND tblcustomfieldsvalues.value = 'Calp'
```

Comment: I apologize, forgot to change the ID in the query. I've changed it from 47 to 17. I want to return the Purchase Amount (fieldid=15) for value column where the client's site is Calp (fieldid=17 and tblcustomfieldsvalue = 'calp')

Comment: Ok then you need to do something like Gordon Linoff says. You can just do it with where clause.